# Pause Javascript Loop During Video

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop, html5-video

Given HTML5 video, is it possible to create a for- or while-loop that will not continue until the video inside it has ended? E.g., the code below should play through the three videos sequentially, not simultaneously.

```
<video id="video0">
    <source src="video0.mp4">
</video>
<video id="video1">
    <source src="video1.mp4">
</video>
<video id="video2">
    <source src="video2.mp4">
</video>
```

.

```
var i=0;
while (i<3) {
    document.getElementById('video'+i).play();
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Do you have control of the video player, or is it a video player from another site that is embedded in yours?

Comment: I'm not using a player, per se, just the standard html5 video tag. So I have full control over it, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A loop will not satisfy your needs here, it's better that you listen for Events.

A list of all events that are connected with Media-Elements can be found at the [W3C Page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/media-elements.html#mediaevents)

So, in your specific case, something like this should help you:

```
var playVideo = function(videoID){
    var video = document.getElementById('video'+videoID);

    if(video){    

        video.play();
        //binding the eventHandler for the event firing at the end of the video
        video.onended = function(e){
            playVideo(videoID++);
        }

        /* 
        Another way of binding the event-listener:
        video.addEventListener('ended',function(){
            playVideo(videoID++);
        });
        */
    }
}

playVideo(0);
```